# Difference between createStatement Parameters for Scrollable ResultSet (JDBC)

Tags: java, jdbc

As I know, the statement object for scroll-able ResultSet is obtained as below.

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement(P1, P2);
```

Here P1 may take

```
ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE
ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE
```

And P2 may take

```
ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE
```

> SCROLL_SENSIVITE or INSENSITIVE indicates, whether the updation of
>   ResultSet will affect the actual database or Not. (Kind of READ_ONLY or Updatable)

So both the parameters are kind of similar and I feel like they are implemented for same purpose.

How are they different or I am missing something here?

Comment: @Mark Sorry did not get. Which part seems to be incorrect ?? Got the above from a Book though.

Comment: That quote is entirely wrong, that is not what `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`/`TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` means; so what is the source of that quote?

Comment: Besides `P1` also takes `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, which might still be read only or updatable...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, `P1` can also take `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, which makes the ResultSet to move only in forward direction. My doubt is with the other two resultSetType. Basically both the parameters (P1 and P2) are confusing me. I want to know, what they actually mean and what are the use cases.

Comment: They are two entirely different things: P1 defines scrolling and if it is sensitive to update outside of the result set, and P2 if you can update through the result set, as already answered by Kayaman.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter `CONCUR_*` determines whether **you** can modify the database through the `ResultSet`. `TYPE_SCROLL_(IN)SENSITIVE` determines whether modifications made to the underlying rows are seen by you while scrolling the `ResultSet`. So `INSENSITIVE` provides a "snapshot" view to the results, they'll never change. `SENSITIVE` provides a "live" view, so if you're scrolling the results for a long time you can see very different values than what was originally returned by the query.

Related, but they're "opposite sides".

Comment: Clarify second sentence with "made by **others**", or something like that.

Comment: Not necessarily others, it can also be about changes done by yourself outside of the result set (eg using another statement inside the same transaction).